# need a macro to auto-open Hyperlinks in excel within a set time each

Tags: excel, vba

I was able to make a somewhat pseudo api for whatsapp using the excel formulas, but to fully automate the process i need a macro that acess the hyperlinks i generate in a cascade like event.
Like i have each link in a cell:
Link1
link2
link3
link4
I need a macro that start opening; link 1, after 5-10seconds it opens link 2 then after 5-10sec it opens link 3 and there after...

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Set Sh = Worksheets("Master")
    With Sh
        Set Rng = .Range("G1:G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    For Each Cell In Rng
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Cell.Value
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

this one nearly solved my issue  `ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Cell.Value`  but i cant get this part pass tru the debuger and im not being able to issue a timer to the sintax

Comment: `Sub Test()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Set Sh = Worksheets("Master")
    With Sh
        Set Rng = .Range("G1:G" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    For Each Cell In Rng
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Cell.Value
    Next Cell
End Sub`
this one nearly solved my issue `ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Cell.Value` but i cant get this part pass tru the debuger and im not being able to issue a timer to the sintax

Comment: Use the [Application.OnTime method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime)